# JSESSIONID not expired, SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME expired

Tags: java, spring-security, session-cookies

So, I have in my application spring security and have introduced remember me functionality when the checkbox is checked in.

I wanted to know what is the exact behavior:
if I set `</remember-me>` tag and specify for the `rememberMeServices` `tokenValiditySeconds` to `20` seconds, shouldn't the session expire and and ask me to log in again?
Do I have to set:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>XX</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

So it matches the `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME` cookie `tokenValiditySeconds` ?

**UPDATE**

Does it matter if I've implemented my own `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`?
I had to override the default `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` coming from spring, because the `PersistentRememberMeToken` did not have any no-arg constructor, thus unable to use hibernate for that, so what I did I just wrote my own `PersistentRememberMeToken`, `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` (which, by the way, do no have anything special beside me introducing the no-arg constructor in `PersistentRememberMeToken`, beside that, it's copy paste from spring's source)

Comment: try it out ? [min chars]

Comment: if you are referring to session-config, I'm not sure if it will work, since I have a timeout of 30 minutes. Problem is that the JSESSIONID is set to next year to expire (`2014`). I am pretty new in spring security. I've looked into a lot of solutions, but not sure if they meet my problem

Comment: the `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME` will expire accordingly, but nothing would happen afterwards. If I try and delete `JSESSIONID` cookie, I would need to enter my credentials again (which I consider would be the okay behavior in the case of the `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a remember-me token which is valid for less than the session-timeout will have no effect on your authentication during that session, if that's what you are asking.

Once you are authenticated during a session, your authentication is valid for the duration of that session, unless you log out or the session expires.

The remember-me token is only considered if you are unauthenticated, otherwise it will be ignored.